# Is there ever a situation where retaining self in a block under ARC is ok?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Let's say my class looks like

```
@interface MyClass {
    MyObject* _object;
    dispatch_queue_t _queue;
}
-(void)myBlocksUsingMethod;
@end
```

Ignoring the semantics of initializing the queue, now I implement

```
-(void)myBlockUsingMethod {
    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
        [_object doSomething];
    });
}
```

As the above code stands, is retaining self in the block ok?

I could rewrite the block like

```
-(void)myBlockUsingMethod {
    __weak MyClass* weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
        MyClass* strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf._object doSomething];
    });
}
```

But now is it necessary to test if `strongSelf == nil` in this situation given that my `_queue` is an iVar of the object I'm retaining?

Also, what happens if my `doSomething` method were to push another block that references `self` onto the same queue?  Will that cause a retain cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: Yes, there are many reasons to do this.  You may know for certain that the object will outlive the block, or you may **want** to create a retain cycle that will be broken manually at a specific time later.

However, in your code, you are doing something quite wrong.  The first method (the one that creates the implicit strong reference to self) should generate a warning.

The second one should not compile.  You have this:

```
[strongSelf._object doSomething];
```

which is invoking a property named `_object` and I doubt that's the case.  So, maybe you meant this:

```
[strongSelf.object doSomething];
```

in which case, you will be fine because if `strongSelf` is `nil` then a message sent to `nil` effectively does nothing.

Or, if there is no property, maybe you really mean this:

```
[strongSelf->_object doSomething];
```

in which case, your program will blow up if strongSelf is nil, because this is not sending a message to `nil` but dereferencing a null pointer.  If you do the latter, you need to check for `nil` explicitly.

Since you do not access `_queue` in the block, that access is fine.  Any direct access of an iVar inside a block must either create a retain cycle to make sure the object is still alive, or it must play the weak-strong-dance and check for nil.

If you use the object in multiple lines, you also need to do the weak-strong-dance because the weak object could dealloc in between accesses (the runtime guarantees that if a __weak is not nil, and accepts a message, that it will stay alive until that message has been handled).

```
[weakObject message1];
// weakObject can become nil here
[weakObject message2];
```

Comment: I meant to type `->` instead of `.` as you correctly pointed out.  Thanks for the writeup.

Answer (score 0):

It should be okay, because the retain cycle is temporary. When the dispatched action is done, it is removed from the queue, so nothing retains the block anymore.